# How to replicate the "Script as Create" functionality from Azure Data Studio in python using pyodbc?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pyodbc, rdbms

I am currently trying to write a script that copies certain tables and procedures from my prod db instance to my dev db instance (I do not want to copy the entire db from prod to dev). I am using SQL Server. Assume that the masking of sensitive data will be handled properly. I want to copy only the following from prod to dev:

1. The entire db definition/schema including all constraints for the specified tables.
2. I also want to copy all of the procedures from prod to dev.

I was able to achieve part 2 by using the built-in `sp_helptext '<procedure-name>'` stored procedure like so:

```
prod_cursor.execute("sp_helptext '<procedure-name>'")
rows = prod_cursor.fetchall()
definition = ''.join(row[0] for row in rows)
dev_cursor.execute(definition)
dev_cursor.commit()
```

I know how I can copy the data from prod to dev but I am kind of stuck on how to copy the entire table definition/schema. Ideally, I want to be able to reproduce the text that is outputted when you right click on a table in Azure Data Studio and then click "Script as Create" like so:
[image]

Ideally, I want to be able to write a script in python to handle all of this functionality for me since I only want to replace certain tables and procedures but not the entire db instance. Let me know if I am going about this wrong or if there are any tools out there that already exist tat can help me automate this process.

Comment: Shouldn't this all be in your source control?

Comment: You can use SMO to script stuff. Not sure it has a python port but you can call `.Net` using some clr python bindings

Comment: [This](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-scripter) looked promising, but given the lack of responses to issues it seems to be an abandoned project.

Comment: sounds like you can use trans replication too

Comment: @SeanLange wish it was. can you explain more about this? what source control can we use for our sql server for this purpose?

Comment: @siggemannen thanks for these recommendations. looking into them now as potential options. Was also wondering if a stored procedure between linked servers using OPENQUERY may work but need to look into that more

Comment: @GordThompson thanks for the recommendation I will check this out!

Comment: Oh yeah, I sometimes use the openquery method,it definitely works for stuff that isn't superlarge

Comment: There are tons of source control options for databases. https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+server+source+control